# Magento 2: using knockout components within a component

Tags: magento2, requirejs, knockout

I am trying to render a new KO component within a existing KO template. I have a PackagePopup component which in the template, renders a PackageFfilter component. I would like to seperate the logic for the filters from the js logic for the items.

PackagePopup template:

```
<div class="content-container">
<section class="pp-grid-filters">
    <!-- ko component: {name:"package-filters-3"} -->  **<-- hardcoded id for testing purposes**
    <!-- /ko -->
</section>
<section class="pp-grid-container" data-bind="foreach: packageItems()" >
        <!-- ko template: { name: 'Company_ProductPackage/packageitem' } -->
        <!-- /ko -->
</section>
```

What this looks like:

[image]

Eventually, i also want to communicate between the two viewmodels.

In the magento template, i try to instantiate the component like this (i have the popup working):

```
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product-package-modal-<?=$productPackage->getId();?>":{
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app":{
                "components":{
                    "package-popup-<?=$productPackage->getId();?>":{
                        "component": "Company_ProductPackage/js/packagepopup",
                        "template" : "Company_ProductPackage/packagepopup",
                        "productPackage" :  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPackageJson($productPackage); ?>,
                        "store_id" : <?=$block->getCurrentStoreId();?>,
                        "mainproduct_id" : <?=$block->getCurrentProductId();?>
                    },
                    "package-filters-<?=$productPackage->getId();?>":{
                        "component": "Company_ProductPackage/js/packagefilter",
                        "template" : "Company_ProductPackage/packagefilter",
                        "productPackageId" :  <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $productPackage->getId() ?>,
                        "store_id" : <?= $block->getCurrentStoreId();?>,
                        "mainproduct_id" : <?= $block->getCurrentProductId();?>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Id's are added to the component names because there can be more instances of the same component on a page.

Witgt he above setup, knockout gives the following error

```
knockout.js:3993 Uncaught Error: Unknown component 'package-filters-3'
```

This must have something to do with the way magento handles components, but i can't really find out why. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working:

```
    <section class="pp-grid-filters" data-bind="scope:'package-filters-3'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</section>
```

Even in knockout templates, the Magento specific scope databind works.

Then the getTemplate is enough to do the trick.